# Backup Visual Studio Code's extensions

Tags: linux, bash, backup, visual-studio-code

I'm using linux and vscode, and want to backup its extensions. I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398449/9971404):

```
code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension
```

My backups are done using rsync, as root, as a cron job. So running that command gives:

`You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument.`

So I do that with some temp directory, and I get a list of extensions. BUT, it creates junk in that directory I then have to delete.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you run this code from cron as a user you use to run code? `sudo -u lonix -- code --list-extensions`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah I might have to do that, but it means my backup scripts need to hardcode usernames. Might be the only way though! Thanks. Maybe add that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your cron job as root, but execute this particular command as a user:

```
sudo -u lonix -- code --list-extensions
```

Or you can add `code --list-extensions` to your user [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) by running `crontab -e` as the user.
The [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) saves configuration in particular users home directory in `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`, so you need to know the username in advance anyway.